# use of Google maps Javascript API v3 in enterprise mobile hybrid app

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova

I am new to google maps API.Was able to make it work in my app without passing any clientid.
When I use clientid I am facing the below mentioned error 
"Google has disabled Maps API for this application....".
As per maps documentation we need to register callers domaian/url.
As I am using maps in hybrid android app I am not clear on what url to register.I see that in request "android-assets/www/xxx" goes to server.

Is there any workaround for this problem?
Am I doing something wrong here?

URL : : http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&client=gme-xxx&callback=yyy

Comment: To use the `clientid` paramater you need to have signed up with google maps premier/enterprise. If you have that then you need to log into your Google Maps Account and enable it for apps. Also if you have a Google Maps Premier/Enterprise account you should be able to contact your account representative to fix the accessibility of your account.

Comment: Thanks for the response will try to do it.

Answer (score -1):

I believe its the web site your using the map from ie www.yourdomain.com

Terran

Comment: We are not using any website to launch.It is a standalone hybrid app which loads html pages locally.